# Going to the UK with Japanese wife

Tags: visa

My wife and I (British national) have decided to live in the UK we currently live in Japan. 
I would like to ask if it is possible to go to the UK together with my Japanese wife whilst I look for work. 
She would enter on a travel visa for and stay for 6 months. 
After the 6 months she would go back to Japan and wait for me to complete my 6 months necessary to get a spouse visa. Which we will then apply for once able.
When we arrive I will be looking for a Job earning over the threshold for a spouse visa. 
My question is if we tell the immigration officer this is our intentions there a chance she would be denied entry? Please feel free to ask me for any additional information that would help answering this question. Or any advice on what to do. Thank you

Comment: Not answering as can't say for sure but she isn't the one looking for work, you are. She is merely visiting for 6 months. If she has the return ticket booked then all should be ok. In particular I wouldn't push the full 6 months, I'd have her leave a bit earlier.